# Creating an Entity from XML

Tags: c#, deserialization

I have the following XML structure

```
<T>
 <F>
  <H>
   <H1>some value</H1>
   <H2>some value</H2>
   <H3>some value</H3>
  </H>
  <O>
   <P>some value</P>
   <TI>some value</TI>
   <TI>some value</TI>
  </O>
  <R>
   <PTY>some value</PTY>
   <PTY>some value</PTY>
   <PTY>some value</PTY>
  </R>
 </F>
<T>
```

I need to parse this xml in C# and get the values out of them to be further exported to a CSV file. 
My query is how do you go about creating an entity for this XML

Comment: Please give an example of how that entity would look like. And how you plan to CSV this.

Comment: This is an [entity](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlentity.php). What do you intend when you talk about an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28VS.80%29.aspx) and its [related attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization%28VS.80%29.aspx).

As long as the XML is not too complex, there's not much work to do.

To read the XML:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableObject));

SerializableObject deserialized;

using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\test.xml", FileMode.Open))
{ 
    deserialized = (SerializableObject)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

The SerializableObject will look like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRootAttribute("T")]
public class SerializableObject
{
    ...
}
```

**BONUS for lazy programmers**: You can just use [Xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx) to brute force create an object from an XML file. Then tweak the results to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LinqToXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to parse xml. StringBuilder will be helpful to produce CSV.

I think these [How Tos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387055.aspx) will be useful. They describe all you needed to parse this xml.

Answer (score 0):

add using System.Xml.Linq;
then you can do something similar to this:

XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"....\People.xml");
var query = from p in xml.Elements("people").Elements("person")
where (int)p.Element("id") == 1
select p;