# SharpRepository: XmlRepository implementation

Tags: xml, repository, sharp-repository

Very simple question so I hope this doesn't get me shot to pieces on Stack.

I am trying to get to grips with the cool SharpRepository package however I have been unsuccessful in finding any useful information on how to impelement the XmlRepository assembly that is bundled with it.

Actually I speak a lie, the nuget version doesn't have it, the github version does but my crap attempts at trying to use it failed.

I compiled the github source then added a reference to SharpRepository.Repository and SharpRepository.XmlRepository, so far so good.

I then did a very simple test by first created a basic entity (name, address, postcode) and then did a quick test as follows:

```
var repo = new XmlRepository<Client, string>("C:\client.xml");
```

When I debug the console app and step into the source code on that line, drill down to the base class XmlRepositoryBase.cs and step through the method LoadItems() I get the an error when I try to execute the line

```
_items = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

I get the following error message:

```
<client xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

The class is very simple for the sake of testing:

```
public class Client
{
   public Int32 Id { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public String Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<client>
  <clientProfile>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>TheFragranceShop</name>
    <description>The Fragrance Shop</description>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </clientProfile>
</client>
```

Thanks in advance and if I manage to work it out will post an update.

Answer (score -1):

I received an answer from the authors:

> The XmlRepository is here:
>   http://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpRepository.XmlRepository/1.3.5.18-unstable
>
> It is marked as pre-release only because it hasn't been used a lot in
>   the real world (as far as I can tell).  I've used it for simple things
>   like storing a small amount of data for simple desktop apps, etc.
>
> It is meant to be used with POCO objects and will store the collection
>   of objects in a single XML file (1 per repository type).  It is not
>   meant to be used for querying existing random XML files, so if that is
>   your purpose then it won't work for you.
>
> Jeff

This makes sense so I am going to use some of the answers already posted on Stack regarding this subject such as:

[Creating an Entity from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938876/creating-an-entity-from-xml)

I think the best solution will be to use a combination of Linq to XML and XML Serli